# Объединение столбцов с суммированием значений в ячейках по одинаковому значению столбца

Tags: python, pandas, объединение

Есть два датайрейма А и В.
А:

```
P1 P2 P3
12 57 aa
23 23 bb
31 23 cc
46 12 dd
```

B:

```
P1 P4  P3
23 NaN bb
56 23  aa
63 34  aa
10 29  cc
```

Нужно объединить их по столбцу P3 так, чтобы в самом столбце Р3 не было дублирующихся значений. В случае, если в датафреймах А и В есть строка с одним и тем же значением в столбце Р3, то значения в других столбцах с одинаковым названием должны суммироваться. Я использую код:

```
C = pd.concat([A, B], sort = True)
```

он дает результат

```
P1 P2  P3 P4
12 57  aa NaN
23 23  bb NaN
31 23  cc NaN
46 12  dd NaN
23 NaN bb NaN
56 NaN aa 23
63 NaN aa 34
10 NaN cc 29
```

Желаемый результат:

```
P1  P2  P3 P4
131 57  aa 57
46  23  bb NaN
41  23  cc 29
46  12  dd NaN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте сделать так:

```
res = pd.concat([df1, df2]).groupby("P3").sum(min_count=1).reset_index()
# min_count в аггрегаторе нужен, чтобы NaN возвращались как NaN, иначевы вместо них
# получите нули.
```

res:

```
   P3   P1    P2    P4
0  aa  131  57.0  57.0
1  bb   46  23.0   NaN
2  cc   41  23.0  29.0
3  dd   46  12.0   NaN
```

Можно еще сделать то же самое с приведением типов:

```
res = pd.concat([df1, df2]).groupby("P3").sum(min_count=1).reset_index().convert_dtypes()
```

res:

```
   P3   P1  P2    P4
0  aa  131  57    57
1  bb   46  23  <NA>
2  cc   41  23    29
3  dd   46  12  <NA>
```

если добавить

```
res = res.reindex(sorted(res.columns), axis=1)
```

то получите исходную сортировку фрейма лексиграфически по именам колонок:

```
    P1  P2  P3    P4
0  131  57  aa    57
1   46  23  bb  <NA>
2   41  23  cc    29
3   46  12  dd  <NA>
```